# Telerik RADGrid - linq and updating

Tags: telerik, radgrid

Telerik's RADGrid, basing on their example on http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/programaticlinqupdates/defaultcs.aspx

Problem:  I can insert and delete, however updating doesn't work.  No error trapped.  Data just doesn't change.

From the code below it looks like Telerik Grid is doing some kung-fu behind the scenes to wire things up.  I can't see the db receiving any update statements.

Question:  anything obvious I'm missing?

```
protected void RadGrid1_UpdateCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            var editableItem = ((GridEditableItem) e.Item);
            var raceId = (Guid) editableItem.GetDataKeyValue("RaceID");

            //retrive entity form the Db
            var race = DbContext.races.Where(n => n.raceid == raceId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (race != null)
            {
                //update entity's state
                editableItem.UpdateValues(race);

                try
                {
                    //submit chanages to Db
                    DbContext.SubmitChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception f)
                {
                    ShowErrorMessage(f);
                }
            }
        }
```

Think I may have to go back to their example.. get their db.. and attack from that point of view.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a Rebind after your update. Trying adding

```
RadGrid1.DataSource = null;
RadGrid1.Rebind();
```

After your call to `DbContext.SubmitChanges();` call, assuming you have implemented _NeedDataSource().

Comment: Manyt thanks.. didn't do it.  I've gone back to the Telerik example and taken out from there.  I'll post a link when I get this above problem solved!  Cheers.

Comment: Didn't quite solve this issue however best examples I found were in http://www.telerik.com/support/documentation-and-tutorials/step-by-step-tutorial-for-ajax.aspx   thanks for the quick response.